# Can CustomModelData NBT be used in armor?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know I can use CustomModelData NBT to have a lot of swords and tools without mods, is there a similar possibility with armor? I don't want to change the shape, only the texture.
Minecraft Java 1.16.5.